# iOS Swift: How to build two different .ipa for different countries on the same project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, software-distribution

I'm writing an iOS app in Swift.
The app is simple, just a UIWebView connected to an URL.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var customWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://A_COUNTRY_URL") {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            customWebView.loadRequest(request)
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

1. I want to keep this in one repository (one project)
2. http://A_COUNTRY_URL is for the .ipa distributed to A country
3. There's another country B needs to be distributed, and the URL is http://B_COUNTRY_URL
4. The two different .ipa should have two different **Bundle ID**

Is it possible to build two different .ipa for one project on Xcode?
If yes, how to do that?

Thanks in advance.
Eric

Comment: Yes. You can add multiple target for same project.

Comment: Do u know how to do that?
Is there any tutorial?
Thanks.

Comment: You can detect the current country code and still use just one .ipa

Comment: It's better to use two different .ipa, because in the future, the two .ipa may have different UI layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this tutorial, Ray Wenderlich http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app explains how to make two versions of an app, one paid and one lite using differents targets as better approach.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `targets` in xcode. Targets are used to reuse the code for different products.

Here are few useful links

[Xcode Target](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html)

[Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app)

Basically you just have to change the target membership of the files that needs to be different. Also you can create macro for targets in build settings to have a check in the code like

```
#ifdef COUNTRY_A
//do for A
#else 
//do for B
#endif
```

For creating [preprocessor macro](http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/)

Answer (score 0):

I did discouraged some logic.
Apple is very sensitive since iOS12 of the same apps with different contents. 
(It happened to me and spoke personally at WWDC2018 with Apple engineers)

so I think if app should show diferent contents, (You gt it from server..)
You should simply change URL ar runtime, based on user prefs (and again.. Apple discourages changes language settings inside apps...)